# Why does 'DIRS' only have an effect when APP_DIRS is False?

Tags: django

Why does 'DIRS' in TEMPLATES in settings.py only have an effect when 'APP_DIRS' is set to False?

I tried to load a custom html widget, but changing the 'DIRS' have not changed the 'Template-loader postmortem' when 'TemplateDoesNotExist' is thrown. When I set the 'APP_DIRS' to False, the 'DIRS' setting suddenly had an effect.

I've tried to search for similar questions, but haven't found an answer. I've also looked through the docs, but neither the paragraph about DIRS nor APP_DIRS mention one working when the other doesn't.

**Example 1:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), '/Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/survey/templates/django/forms/widgets'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Gives this output:

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nested_admin/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/survey/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tellme/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tinymce/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/jonas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/templates/horizontal_select.html (Source does not exist)
```

**Example 2:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), '/Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/survey/templates/django/forms/widgets'],
    'APP_DIRS': False,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

gives this output:

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/templates/survey/survey_detail.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/survey/templates/django/forms/widgets/survey/survey_detail.html (Source does not exist)
```

If I understand the 'engine django' correctly, the last line of example 2 ('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/jonas/Documents/jobb/dynamicSurvey/survey/templates/django/forms/widgets/survey/') should alse be looked for in example 1, if the DIRS setting had an effect.

I'm new to Stack, so feel free to criticize my question.

Comment: Which Django version is this?

Comment: Its Django 1.11.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `FORM_RENDERER` setting to use the [`TemplatesSetting`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#templatessetting) renderer. It will use the configuration from your `TEMPLATES` setting.

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

As the docs suggest, I would set `'APP_DIRS'` to `True` again, and add `django.forms` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` so that Django can find the default templates.

Comment: 'django.forms' was already added to 'INSTALLED_APPS'. I set the FORM_RENDERER as you said, but still no effect. (It's the default, anyways?) I also added the result from 'django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'' as mentioned in [TemplatesSetting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#templatessetting) to 'DIRS'. 'APP_DIRS' is also set to True.

Comment: The default is `DjangoTemplates`. I suggested to use `TemplatesSetting` (although I accidentally copy-pasted `django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates` at first). You don't have to add the result from `django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'` if you already have `APP_DIRS` set to `True` and include `django.forms` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.